# Get Height/Width of Parent Box

Tags: luatex, tex-core, context

In cases when input text to be typeset is separate from the structured template, can the input determine the height and width of its containing box?

An example input. Question marks (?) to be substituted (Lua or TeX).

```
The width of the parent box is ?

The height of the parent box is ?
```

Several possible templates:

```
\ruledhbox to 10cm{\vbox to 4cm{ \input input }} % 10cm by 4cm
```

```
\ruledvbox to 4cm{\hsize=10cm \input input } % 10cm by 4cm
```

```
\framed
    [width=10cm,
     height=4cm,
     align={middle,lohi},
     offset=0.5cm]
    { \input input } % 9cm by 3cm
```

Dimensions are meaningless until the box has been stored, so that's probably the place to start.

---

My expansion of the `\aftergroup`+`\lastbox` [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533784/174577):

```
\typeset{\hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: \parwd }}}}
```

```
{   \let\parht\askparent\let\parwd\askparent\let\pardp\askparent
    \setbox0=\hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: \parwd }}}
    \hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: \parwd }}}
}
```

```
{   \let\parht\askparent\let\parwd\askparent\let\pardp\askparent
    \setbox0=\hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: \parwd }}}
    \hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: \askparent }}}
}
```

```
{   \let\parht\askparent\let\parwd\askparent\let\pardp\askparent
    \setbox0=\hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: \parwd }}}
    \hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: } \afterafter }}
}
```

```
{   \let\parht\askparent\let\parwd\askparent\let\pardp\askparent
    \setbox0=\hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: \parwd }}}
    \hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: }} \after }
}
```

```
{   \let\parht\askparent\let\parwd\askparent\let\pardp\askparent
    \setbox0=\hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: \parwd }}}
    \hbox to50pt{
        \setbox\storelast=\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: }}
        \xdef\parht{\the\ht\storelast}
        \xdef\parwd{\the\wd\storelast}
        \xdef\pardp{\the\dp\storelast}
        \ifvmode\nointerlineskip\fi\box\storelast}
}
```

```
{   \let\parht\askparent\let\parwd\askparent\let\pardp\askparent
    \setbox0=\hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: \parwd }}}
    \hbox to50pt{
        \setbox\storelast=\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: }}
        \xdef\parht{\the\ht\storelast}
        \xdef\parwd{\the\wd\storelast}
        \xdef\pardp{\the\dp\storelast}
        \vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{width: }}}
}
```

Comment: I thought I had seen a similar question a few years ago but I can't find it.

Comment: With bare TeX boxes I don't think it is possible, but within a `\framed` you can just query `\framedparameter{width}` to get the width.

Comment: Just waiting for someone from LuaTeX to chime in. "Why yes, we *do* have pointers for backtracking up the node tree". So many good answer.

Comment: @user19087 the mistake you made with the expansion is that the `\setbox0` assignment is carried out before anything in the following line is evaluated, including the call to `\parwd` in the assignment. therefore, everything you did afterwards is actually done in the `\setbox0` line first, and after that the rest is expanded, but this time `\parwd` is the width of the parent box.

Comment: Can you show with a real example what you're trying to achive because there are other ways to determine the width and height of the box size, e.g. many of ConTeXts tabl environment use multiple passes to determine the size of each cell. When you do something similar in combination with a buffer to store the content of the box you can get the size of the box and show it afterwards in the box.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm trying to do. I'll have an example later. In the meantime, where did the missing 0.8pt go? `\bTABLE[width=200pt,offset=0pt,frame=off]\bTR\bTD\framedwidth\eTD\eTR\eTABLE%`  => 199.2pt.

Comment: Even if `frame=off`, there must be `rulethickness=0pt` otherwise 0.8pt will be consumed. I've encountered that with nested frames as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `\framed` for your texts you can get the width of the content in the box with the `\framedwidth` and `\framedheight` commands. A restriction here is that you get only usable value when the `width` or `height` settings contains a length larger than `0pt`.

```
\starttext

\startframed[width=200pt,height=80pt,offset=10pt,rulethickness=0.5pt]
     Width: \framedwidth \par
    Height: \framedheight
\stopframed

\stoptext
```

[image]

To get the values of the `width` and `height` keys you can use the `\localwidth` and `\localheight` commands. Here you should be ware of that ConTeXt delivers whathever value was set with the key, i.e. when you set `width=fit` the `\localwidth` commands gives you `fit` as argument.

```
\starttext

\startframed[width=200pt,height=80pt,offset=10pt,rulethickness=0.5pt]
     Width: \localwidth \par
    Height: \localheight
\stopframed

\stoptext
```

[image]

The last possible value can be used for the background of a frame but unlike the previous methods you get the correct `width` or `height` of the frame even with settings like `width=fit`.

```
\defineoverlay
  [boxdimensions]
  [\vbox\bgroup
     \hbox {Width: \overlaywidth}
     \hbox{Height: \overlayheight}
   \egroup]

\setupframed % don't make global framed settings in a document
  [background=boxdimensions]

\starttext

\startframed[width=200pt,height=80pt,offset=10pt,rulethickness=0.5pt]
    %
\stopframed

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I assume `\local<key>` command is a subset of `\framedparameter{<key>}`? If the key is missing, ConTeXt complains `! Missing number, treated as zero`. Is it possible to fallback to other values, i.e. `loffset -> offset -> 0`?

Comment: If I have `width`, `offset`, and `loffset` then `framedwidth = width - 2*offset - loffset`. Is this right? I assumed it would be `framedwidth = width - offset - loffset`? Is this the way ConTeXt has always worked, or is `\framedwidth` wrong?

Comment: The `offset` value is applied on all four sides while the `loffset` etc. values are only applied on the requested in addition to the global `offset` value. When you use the `\local<key>` commands for a calculation you have to check first if it's empty or contain a valid dimension. The value of `\framedwidth` is `width - 2*offset - loffset - roffset - 2*rulethickness`.

Answer (score 1):

This "solution" is surely not universal and well thought through, but it works for me in simple cases, with plain TeX:

```
\newbox\storelast
\def\after{\setbox\storelast=\lastbox
  {\globaldefs=1
  \edef\parht{\the\ht\storelast}
  \edef\parwd{\the\wd\storelast}
  \edef\pardp{\the\dp\storelast}}
  \ifvmode\nointerlineskip\fi\box\storelast}
\def\afterafter{\aftergroup\after}
\def\askparent{\aftergroup\afterafter}

\def\typeset#1{\let\parht\askparent\let\parwd\askparent\let\pardp\askparent
  {\globaldefs=-1 \setbox0#1}#1}
```

Afterwards, you can typeset the template with `\typeset{...}`. In the input, you can use `\parwd`, `\parht` and `\pardp` to get the width, height and depth of the parent box, respectively. The argument of `\typeset` **has to be a box** (it has to start with `\hbox`, `\vbox` ...).

For example, I have a file called `input.tex` that contains

`width \parwd\ height \parht`.

Then, the following lines

```
\typeset{\hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{\input input }}}}
\typeset{\vbox to50pt{\hbox to40pt{\vbox to30pt{\input input }}}}
```

print (apart from many over/underfull boxes)

```
width 30.0pt height 40.0pt
width 40.0pt height 30.0pt
```

correctly. However,

- I have no idea how well this behaves for more complex constructs;
- **Edit:** As pointed out by Henri Menke in the comments, typesetting the box twice (with `\setbox0#1` followed by `#1`) might lead to unexpected side effects, for example if counters are increased in the box. I tried to reduce that problem by evaluating the `\setbox0#1` in a group with `\globaldefs=-1`, but this might change the dimensions of the box if packages relying on global definitions are used, such as `tikz`, yielding incorrect results;
- it assumes that the commands `\parht` etc. are **not used inside a group** other than the ones created by the boxes;
- it will only work if the parent box is **not on the main vertical list** as it uses `\lastbox` to determine the box dimensions, which is empty in external vertical mode.

For the last point, consider the example above, but now we are interested in the dimensions of the outermost box:

```
\typeset{\hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{\input input }}}}
\typeset{\vbox to50pt{\hbox to40pt{\vbox to30pt{\input input }}}}
```

would print

```
width 0.0pt height 0.0pt
width 0.0pt height 0.0pt
```

because the outermost box is set in external vertical mode. In this case, you would have to wrap your template with another box, like

```
\typeset{\hbox{\hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{}\input input }}}}
\typeset{\hbox{\vbox to50pt{\hbox to40pt{\vbox to30pt{}\input input }}}}
```

printing

```
width 50.0pt height 40.0pt
width 40.0pt height 50.0pt
```

as expected.

Comment: I understand where this is going but can't match the output when expanding by hand. What is the point of `\setbox0`? The `\parwd` in `width \parwd` is expanded to the `xdef`s two boxes upwards, leaving nothing after "width". And why not just call `\after` before `\input`, allowing `\parht` etc to be used within nested groups?

Comment: *I will edit temporarily edit my question to show my expansion.*

Comment: the problem is that if you would just use the template as it is and call `\after` before `\input`, the `\xdef` assignments are carried out only after the input was read, so that `\parwd` does not have an effect (as you observed). so I do it in two passes: `\setbox0#1` serves to have the assignments carried out (and the use of `\setbox` hides the result), and then the argument is set again, but this time `\parwd` has its final meaning.

Comment: would it be useful to you if I added a more elaborate explanation in my answer?

Comment: No, that makes sense now. And it explains why something like this isn't possible, as much as I would prefer: `{\hbox to50pt{\vbox to40pt{\hbox to30pt{\askparent width: \parwd }}}}`. Not possible, right?

Comment: yeah I don't think that's possible in the general case as the parameters of the box aren't determined before it has been set once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105892/discussion-between-user19087-and-wave).

Comment: This is not a good idea.  You are typesetting the box twice, i.e. you are evaluating the content twice.  If you, for example, increase a counter inside the box, you will increase it twice.

Comment: @HenriMenke That's true. What about doing the `\setbox0` in a group with `\globaldefs=-1` (and `\after` temporarily changing that back)?

Comment: @wave There is no way to do this without side-effects.  If you set `\globaldefs=-1` you can no longer use TikZ patterns, shadings, or fadings inside, because it uses global variables to count and deduplicate the corresponding PDF objects (other packages might do similar things, maybe `hyperref`?).

Comment: @HenriMenke thanks for pointing that out, I have modified my answer to include your comment. I guess my general remark that this might only work for simple situations holds then.

Comment: @wave “dangerous side effects” sounds very dramatic.  Maybe call it “unexpected”?  It's not like it's going to wipe your hard drive.

Comment: @HenriMenke true :D I've seen that phrase in such exaggerated use quite often, seems like I was guilty of that myself in this case